# Fragment Dialog Animating correctly but layout is completely black

Tags: java, android, android-animation

This is my dialogFragment class below:

```
public static class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {
        @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.styleDialog);
            // Get the layout inflater
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

            // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
            // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
            builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null));

            return builder.create();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            if (getDialog() == null) {
                return;
            }

            DisplayMetrics metrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            float dpValue = 170f;
            float fPixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dpValue, metrics);

            int dialogWidth = Math.round(fPixels);
            int dialogHeight = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

            if (getDialog().getWindow() != null) {
                getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(dialogWidth, dialogHeight);
            }

        }
    }
```

This method is called from my activity to show my dialog:

```
private void showDialog() {
    DialogFragment dialogFragment = new MyDialog();
    dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), MyDialog.class.getName());
}
```

This is my style.xml and anim.xml respectively:

```
<style name="styleDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/CustomDialogAnimation</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomDialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/animate_down_side_opens_up</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@android:anim/slide_out_right</item>
</style>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="0%"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
```

**CURRENT SITUATION:**
My dialog is sliding in an open expansion from up to down and this is exactly what I want.

**PROBLEM:**
However, the dialog itself is completely black and does not contain any of the views.

[image]

**Note:** Without any animation, the dialog will contain its layout view elements.

**EDIT:** Adding custom dialog layout below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numberOneText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/numberOne"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numberTwoText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/numberTwo"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numberThreeText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/numberThree"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**NOTICE:** Changing the AlertDialog class import from android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog to android.app.AlertDialog changed the UI of the custom dialog to a double squared dialog. Image attached below:

[image]

Comment: Somehow I don't manage to reproduce the error. Tested with two emulators (Api level 23 and 24) and some "Hello World" TextView in a LinearLayout (you did not include layout/custom_dialog.xml)

Comment: I will go ahead and include it even though it's kinda irrelevant for this scenario.

Comment: I'd agree it's irrelevant but I used a ConstraintLayout which happened to be there before switching to the LinearLayout which worked for me. The ConstraintLayout was not shown. My main point though was that with my dummy layout the animation worked. So I was not able to reproduce the error.

Comment: @0X0nosugar I tried replacing my LinearLayout with ConstraintLayout but it did not work for me. One thing that I just noticed is changing the AlertDialog class import changed the dialog UI. I edited the question again and added that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all there, you just can't see it. Change your style like this (add one line, the first one inside the first style tag):

```
<style name="styleDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/CustomDialogAnimation</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomDialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/anim</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@android:anim/slide_out_right</item>
</style>
```

and your layout and its content becomes visible. It may not look as you want it, but you can work from there. See for yourself:

[image]

Tested with android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.

Comment: I'm wondering how you spotted that and how I missed that ! :D Works great.

Comment: Black was the background and black is the default color of text, so I just tried a non default one.